# jOOQ - Listener

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ to interact with a local MySQL database.
More specifically I'm using the only jOOQ generated DAOs stored in a static class.
I wish if there were some "ready to use" listeners to catch insert / update / delete queries (don't care about select / fetch ones).
If not, any suggestion on how to code one, if it is possible to make a generic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "using the only jOOQ generated DAOs", but there are two listeners that might apply to your case

- [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordListener.html) to listen to any lifecycle events caused by [`UpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html) methods
- [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) to listen to any lifecycle events caused by query executions

Comment: I meant that with the jOOQ generator I generate DAOs classes. In the whole project, I use only these DAOs to interact with the database.
Thank you for the answer, I guess I can use just the RecordListener

Comment: @gekoramybean: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, in that case, you might be able to use `RecordListener`, although there is no formal guarantee that `DAO` will pass by that listener for all `DAO` methods!